# React spread operator (...props) not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to pass a GeolocationCoordinates object to a child component using the spread operator (https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#spread-attributes) but for some reason in the child props it is just an empty object:

```js
interface HUDState {
    geoCoords: GeolocationCoordinates | null
    login: boolean
}

function MainHUD(props: HUDState) {
    console.log('MainHUD props:', props)
   
    return (
        <Background>
            {
             props.geoCoords !== null && props.geoCoords !== undefined ? 
                 <Map {...props.geoCoords} /> 
            : 
              null
            }
        </Background>
    )
}

function Map(props: GeolocationCoordinates) {
    console.log('Map props:', props)

        return (
            <MapContainer style={MapContainerStyle} center={[props.latitude, props.longitude]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
            </MapContainer>
        )
}
```

console (Map child props is empty):

```
MainHUD props: Object { login: false, geoCoords: GeolocationCoordinates }
Map props: Object {  } <-- Why is this empty here?
```

However if specify the props manually in the parent component when defining the child map tag everything works (actually I get warnings Map is missing properties because I only want latitude and longitude):

```js
<Map latitude={props.geoCoords.latitude} longitude={props.geoCoords.longitude} />
```

console (Map child props are defined now):

```
Map props: Object { latitude: 40.2927067, longitude: -73.9837427 } <-- Not empty now!
```

I am using webpack/babel to transpile my tsx back into javascript and it is not throwing any errors. I've included the `"@babel/plugin-transform-spread"` even though this post (https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-spread) says it should be included in the `"@babel/env"` preset. Also I added the plugin to both webpack.config.js and .babelrc because I wasn't sure which one needed it.

webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/App.tsx'),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "babel-loader",
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                "@babel/env",
                                "@babel/react",
                                "@babel/typescript"
                            ],
                            plugins: [
                                ["@babel/plugin-transform-spread", {
                                    "loose": true
                                }]
                            ]
                        },
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.json', '.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
        },
        server: {
            type: 'https',
            options: {
                key: './example.com+4-key.pem',
                cert: './example.com+4.pem',
            }
        }
    }
}
```

.babelrc:

```json
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-transform-spread",
            {
                "loose": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "example.com",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.40.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-spread": "^7.19.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
}
```

I've been so fed I added

```js
props.geoCoords !== null && props.geoCoords !== undefined
```

before rendering the child Map component and it still does nothing. I also understand the spread operator is meant iterables like arrays but this in React and in the React example I linked above it is used for props objects. This is why I added the loose option in the configs and it still does not help. Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about how to use this operator? Is there an issue with my setup?

I've searched a bunch on this issue and most people seem to try to use the operator on objects outside of React or have a problem transpiling the operator in the first place and this is not my issue. I get that this is optional and I can build the rest of my app without this feature but I forsee my components getting much more complicated and being able to just pass entire props object without specifying each field manually would be a big help. Big thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Empty objects are considered `true` when encountered in a [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean) context. Take a look here: [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

```
const geoCoords = {};

console.log(geoCoords !== null && geoCoords !== undefined); // true
```

So if `geoCoords` is an empty object (`{}`), `<Map {...props.geoCoords} />` will still be rendered, but no prop will be passed.

Ensure `geoCoords` is not an empty object and you can do the following:

```
<Background>
  {props.geoCoords && <Map {...props.geoCoords} />}
</Background>
```

Or also check if is an empty object:

```
<Background>
    {props.geoCoords && Object.keys(props.geoCoords).length > 0 && (
      <Map {...props.geoCoords} />
    )}
</Background>
```